# BS4 module not found

Tags: python, cmd, beautifulsoup, pip

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/project.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Guys any idea why i get this error.
Ive installed bs4 with cmd and pip

Comment: Are you working in a virtual environment?

Comment: What version of python are you using? Are you running from a command line? Do you have multiple python versions installed ?

Comment: Can you run this from command line and paste the output? python -c 'help("modules")'

Comment: If you're running your script from the command prompt as, e.g., `python D:\preoject.py` then you should install BeautifulSoup via `python -m pip install bs4` to ensure you're installing into the same python environment.

Comment: Yes ive tried anything but still it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Where do i have to install the module i am really confused
Some of them work and some of them dont
For example, bs4 doesnt but tkinter does